# Создание игры на С#

Tags: c#, winforms, разработка-игр

Хочу создать игру "вопросник" по типу "Кто хочет стать миллионером". Есть базовые знания С#, однако абсолютно не владею Windows Forms. Пытаюсь как-то разобраться по ходу. Для создания игры решил сначала создать базу данных с вопросами в SQL, а затем уже на ее основе создать игру. И если с SQL я смог разобраться, то создание самого приложения вызывает кучу вопросов. Прошу подсказать ресурсы для обучения работе с windows forms и подсказать в правильном направлении ли я вообще двигаюсь. Может есть способ создать игру проще, например без использования баз данных впринципе. Разносите в общем.

Comment: `например без использования баз данных впринципе` -  смотря для чего игра. Если лишь бы была - то можно хоть хардокорно в коде задать вопросы с ответами

Comment: Скорее для того, чтобы разобраться как и что можно сделать. Можно и прямо в коде, но как уж слишком деревянно по-моему.

Comment: `но как уж слишком деревянно по-моему.` - конечно, потому что все подходы как и что будет написано, зависят от целей. В данном случае они не ясны, отсюда и вариант с хардкором.

Comment: Цель  - научиться создавать работающее приложение для пк и слезть наконец с консоли. Ну а если учиться, то нужно учится делать все правильно, поэтому я и решил спросить у знающих людей.

Comment: Если вы хотите писать игру и разобраться с настольными приложениями, рекомендую начать с WPF ( хорошим стартом будет [эта книжка](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/21462174/) )

Comment: Если именно WinForms, то начать можно отсюда https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd492132.aspx (далее по ссылкам), ну и список литературы из комментария выше в помощь. Если есть желание разобраться - материалов на MSDN достаточно, а тонкости можно тут поискать или спросить. По поводу WPF не уверен, да там можно много красивостей делать довольно легко, но перед этим придется глубоко нырнуть в сопутствующую теорию, у форм порог вхождения все таки ниже, но если не боитесь трудностей - можно и с WPF  начать.